# How do I solve $\sin^2 x=\cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve a trigonometric equation, but I'm a bit stuck. The equation is this:

- $\sin^2 x = \cos x$

So far what I've done looks like this:

- $\sin^2 x - \cos x = 0$

  $ (1 - \cos^2 x) - \cos x = 0$

  $-\cos^2 x - \cos x + 1 = 0$

But from there I don't know how to factor it to get onwards to evaluating $x$ for separate cosine terms. Have I gone wrong somewhere, or am I simply not seeing the proper way to factor this?

Comment: Just solve it as you would solve any quadratic equation, just not in $x$, but in $\cos x$.

Comment: In other words, let $y=\cos x$. Solve for $y$. Then solve for $x$.

Comment: @amWhy: I think you made a sign error. This quadratic has real roots.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, yep, $\sin^2x$ definitely intersects $\cos x$ in $(0, \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sin^2 x = \cos x$$
$$1-\cos^2 x -\cos x= 0$$
$-1\leq\cos x=t\leq 1$
$$t^2+t-1=0$$
$$t_{1}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\in[-1,1],t_{2}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}<-1,t_2\notin[-1,1]$$
$$x_1=\arccos t_1$$

Comment: but $$t_{1}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}<1$$

Comment: @nadia-liza: You mean "$< -1$".

Comment: @nadia-liza: $t_1$ is obviously not a solution, but $t_2=\arccos\dfrac1\phi$ however is.

Comment: @nadia-liza. My answer is edited.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the right square bracket in the above expression $\interval{-1,1}$ prints more faintly than the left square bracket? I've noticed this throughout MSE. It may be a LaTex thing.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what's happening here... I don't understand this answer.

Comment: Actually, after trying it out on paper myself, it clicked. I get it now, thanks!